# What is $\int x e^{ax} \cos(bx)dx$?

Tags: integration

What are
$$\int x e^{ax} \cos(bx)dx$$
and
$$\int x e^{ax} \sin(bx)dx?$$

Comment: These are senseless comments.  Please expand on what you are trying to say.

Comment: Use integration by parts. Remember the product rule?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I think he just means the indefinite integral evaluated for $a\ne 0$ and $b\ne 0$ (the non-trivial solutions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can see that

$$\int e^{ax}\cos(bx)\ dx=\Re\int e^{(a+bi)x}\ dx=\frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}\left(a\cos(bx)+b\sin(bx)\right)+c$$

Likewise,

$$\int e^{ax}\sin(bx)\ dx=\Im\int e^{(a+bi)x}\ dx=\frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}\left(a\sin(bx)-b\cos(bx)\right)+c$$

And lastly differentiate each w.r.t. $a$ to reveal

$$\int xe^{ax}\cos(bx)\ dx=\frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}\left((ax+1-\frac{2a}{a^2+b^2})\cos(bx)+(bx-\frac{2a}{a^2+b^2})\sin(bx)\right)+c$$

$$\int e^{ax}\sin(bx)\ dx=\frac{e^{ax}}{a^2+b^2}\left((ax+1-\frac{2a}{a^2+b^2})\sin(bx)-(bx+\frac{2a}{a^2+b^2})\cos(bx\right)+c$$

Comment: Great! Thank you very much!

Comment: @regress Sure, your welcome.  :D

Comment: (honestly did it this way just to avoid integration by parts, since that is probably the normal method)

Answer (score 2):

Integration by parts for 3 functions -

> $$\int fgh'\ dx=fgh-\int fg'h+f'gh\ dx$$

[Taking reference to this link you can solve above integrals.](https://owlcation.com/stem/How-to-Integrate-xexcosx-and-xsinxex)

Comment: Your welcome...

Comment: T_T this problem was made to kill my soul.  Triple integration by parts?  Noooppppeeeeee!  (You could do the integration by parts on just $e^{ax}\cos(bx)$ like I did and then just differentiate like I did.)

Comment: Hahaha... Its very difficult to solve triple integrals by parts. And sometimes irritated me also. And link I provided is very nice.

Comment: Yeah.  Personally, I've never been forced into IBP due to methods like above.